# javascript: loop through object properties

Tags: javascript

I'm building an object dynamically like this:

```
scope.filters[scope.col.field] = { value: scope.filterValue, operator: scope.filterOperator };
```

where scope.col.field is a string.

Then how do I loop through scope.filters in order to access value and operator for the various properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example:

```
for (var fieldName in scope.filters) {
    if (!scope.filters.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
        alert(fieldName + ": " + scope.filters[fieldName]);
    }
}
```

`for..in` will go through all the members of an object.

It's a best practice to always check that the variable is its own member, so you don't pick up any other inherited functions or members. [Here](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/) is a good explanation and example regarding why you should use `hasOwnProperty`.

I just set up an alert, but you can obviously do whatever you need with each `fieldName` and its value.  Note, in this case, you'll get a lot of alerts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `in` operator, combined with the `for` loop. Check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

or try like this:-

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

In your case:-

```
for (var fieldName in scope.filters) {
if (scope.filters.hasOwnProperty(fieldName))
{
 //.....
}
```