# how to create for loop in map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create for loop statement in map in javascript to update every item in it

```
var map = new Object();
map[key] = value;
map[key1] = value1;
```

i want to loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
   //do something for map[key]
```

however, it´s not clear for me *from where* can I get `map.length` and how can I obtain `key` from `i`.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) is what you looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: loop through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898743/javascript-loop-through-object-properties)

Comment: from where do you get the `map.length`?

Comment: this is my exactly my question, i want to know how to loop inside map like this map

Answer (score 0):

To iterate an object you can do something like this:

```
var map = new Object();
map['key']= 'value';
map['key1'] = 'value1';
//Loop the object key-value pairs
for(var key in map){
 console.log(key + "-->"+ map[key])
}

//OR THIS WAY

var map = new Object();
map.key= 'value';
map.key1 = 'value1';
for(var key in map){
 console.log(key + "-->"+ map.key)
}
```

Comment: In addition, is not a bad idea to use dot notations: `map.key`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper declaration for Map and `forEach` method to iterate over the map

```
var usersMap = new Map();
usersMap.set(1, "Malo");
usersMap.set(2, "bob");
usersMap.set(3, "jane");

usersMap.forEach(function (username, userId) {
  console.log(userId, username);
  if (userId === 1) {
     console.log("We found Malo.");
  }
});
```